# MachineLearning or DecisionTree for job matching?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm working on a job matching app and I was wondering what's the best way to match elements between themselves to sort the best result?

In my mind it's by going through a decision tree as we already know the structure of the element and the expected result.
However, would the machinelearning be an alternate solution or is it worthless to do so?

I might be mistaken but to me ML is efficient for sorting datas which at first sight don't have obvious common points, right?

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: It seems to be more appropriate for the [data science forum](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Decision tree is part of ML. Maybe you means more complex algorithm than decision tree, like xgboost or neural network.

xgboost or neural network are good when you have too much variables to make sense to create manually a decision tree.

Decision tree is better when you want to control your algorithm (for exemple, for ethical or managerial reasons).

xgboost and unsupervised thec are also good to create the boundaries used in your decision tree. For exemple, should you create a category 18-25 or 18-30, etc..

Considering the complexity of such a problem, with time and geographical constrain, using advanced algorithms seems a good idea to me.

Have a look at that Kaggle competition which seems close to your problem, it may give you some good insight:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/job-recommendation/data